# Fontforge doesn't support legacy scripting?

Tags: fontforge

In my Fontforge version `fontforge 11:21 UTC 24-Sep-2017` under File > Execute script the FF button is disabled. Is it not possible any more to execute native legacy scripts from within FF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That version is very out of date.

While the legacy scripting language is recommended against, it still works at least as of the 20<sup>th</sup> Anniversary Release, [20201107](https://github.com/fontforge/fontforge/releases/tag/20201107), and there's no plan to remove it (I'm one of the maintainers).